# Problema com sessão Codeigniter erro

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Estou com um pequeno problema de login com codeigniter, apos fazer o login ele não transfere os dados pela sessão.
fiz os seguintes teste:

- Imprimi a sessão no controler [ok, imprimiu dados correto]
- Imprimi a sessão em outro controler [não imprimiu nada]
- limpei Cache

Login:

```
public function login(){
        $usuario    =   $this->input->post('usuario'); // recebe name usuario pelo post
        $senha      =   $this->input->post('senha');
        $this->db->where('usuario', $usuario); // pega o valor igual ao usuario do post no banco
        $this->db->where('senha', $senha);
        $this->db->where('ativo',1);
        $usuario = $this->db->get('usuarios')->result();
        if (count($usuario)===1) {
            $dados  = array(
                'usuario'=>$usuario[0]->usuario,
                'logado'=> TRUE 
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($dados);
            //print_r($dados);
            redirect('administracao/categorias');
        }else{
            echo heading('Usuario não encontrado', 2);
        }
    }
```

Verificação do Login:

```
class Categorias extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->userdata('usuario') || !$this->session->userdata('logado')) {
            redirect('administracao/home');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código fonte?

Comment: @rray Atualizem com o codigo

Answer (score 2):

Bom, não sei ao certo se é a solução, mas tente gravar sessão por sessão no seu código. Verifique sempre se você está chamando a library `session` no seu controller ou no seu `autoload.php`.

**Atualizei o código, deixando mais correto**

Login:

```
public function login(){
        $usuario    =   $this->input->post('usuario'); // recebe name usuario pelo post
        $senha      =   $this->input->post('senha');
        $this->db->where('usuario', $usuario); // pega o valor igual ao usuario do post no banco
        $this->db->where('senha', $senha);
        $this->db->where('ativo',1);
        $usuario = $this->db->get('usuarios');
        if ($usuario->num_rows() > 0) {

            $this->session->set_userdata('usuario', $usuario);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logado', TRUE);

            //print_r($dados);
            redirect('administracao/categorias');
        }else{
            echo heading('Usuario não encontrado', 2);
        }
    }
```

Verifique também o seu `config.php` se as configurações de sessão estão mais ou menos assim:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, apenas limpei o histórico do navegador e voltou ao normal